# In Excel web add-in how can I handle Oauth from non-Microsoft providers

Tags: excel

I'm developing an add-in with Javascript that integrates with https://data.world. To get started I'm pointing the add-in to an existing web app https://dw_experiments_dev.hardworkingcoder.com I added that site and data.world as AppDomains. In a regular browser I can login via Ouath. But with Excel I get through the auth process and then see my homepage but as a logged out users. My app is using sessionStorage.